# Cyclic vs Symmetric Polynomials

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

I visited brilliant.org and I found this from the Cyclic Polynomials wiki. Note that for the polynomial shown in the pic, if we leave it in its current form, we might see that, if we change $(x,\ y,\ z)$ in a symmetrical way, it *looks* not the same. However, if we expand it, we will see that it remains the same even if we change $(x,\ y,\ z)$ in a symmetrical way. For me, this polynomial is also symmetrical. Is my concept wrong or the site wrong?

**NOTE**. The polynomial is $$ P(x, y, z)=(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2.$$
[image: Cyclic Polynomials. *Brilliant.org*. Retrieved 16:20, September 23, 2018, from https://brilliant.org/wiki/cyclic-polynomials/]

Comment: I have added the polynomial to the post. It is always better not to include external images unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: I understand :) Thank you @GiuseppeNegro

Answer (score 1):

You are right: $P(x,y,z)$ **is** a symmetric polynomial: if we exchange any two variables, we get again the same polynomial.